# fork() multiple times with a timer

Tags: c, linux, time, fork

I have this piece of code:

```
    int pidArr[128];
    int i=0;
    clock_t begin;
    double time_spent; 
    begin = clock();
    while(1) {
        time_spent = (double)(clock() - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; 
        if (time_spent>=2.0){ break; }
        pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0){
            pidArr[i] = getpid();
            i++;
        }
    }
```

I want to fork() for 2 seconds to fill my pid array and break from the loop but it's not happend & my virtual machine crash badly.

I'll appreciate any help to fix it.

Comment: You are creating an exponential number of processes drying the system resources most probably.

Comment: I guess so, I tried for 2 hours to figure out how to fix it but I didn't succeed :(

Comment: Why are you using a timer?

Comment: It's a requirement in my homework.. I'm a cs student

Comment: And what is the requirement? to see how many forks were run in them 2 seconds?

Comment: You've written a pretty effective fork bomb there. You probably want the parent process not to keep forking after it has forked the first child.

Comment: I've abstract the question. it's a simulation of washing machine for cars. each child process is a "car" and they arriving each few seconds. I have to use a timer and not a loop while i'm fork()ing.

Comment: @alaniwi hehe the nagasaki of the fork bombs. I'm thinking to assign it to my lecturer.

Comment: Well even if each process forks only once, so that the number of processes grows linearly with time, you will probably be forking enough times to harm the system (and overflow your pid array) long before the 2 seconds is up. But as you have it, with every iteration of the loop the number of processes doubles because both the parent and the child will continue to fork, so you have very rapid exponential growth. It is no surprise that your VM crashes.

Comment: This is a pretty traditional assignment in some CS courses. Depending on your perspective, other names for it are *tough love* or *hazing*. In the days when students worked in computer labs on shared workstations, the week of the fork assignment was always the worst week of the semester because students were constantly crashing the machines, and rebooting took a while.

Comment: @Caleb absolutely true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have accidentaly created a fork bomb, the problem is that when the timer is elapsed you should kill all the proccesses (or do whatever you want with this pidarr and after kill all the threads), like this example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <signal.h>

// maybe there is a standard macro or something like that
// but on my machine in /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max there is 4194304
#define PID_MAX 4194304

pid_t pidarr[PID_MAX];

static void
sigalrmHandler(int sig)
{
  for(int i = 1; i <= PID_MAX; i++){
    printf("Killing %ld\n",(long)pidarr[i]);
    kill(pidarr[i],SIGKILL);
  }
}

int main(void){
  struct sigaction sa;
  struct itimerval new_timer;

  pidarr[0] = getpid();

  sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
  sa.sa_flags = 0;
  sa.sa_handler = sigalrmHandler;
  if(sigaction(SIGALRM,&sa,NULL) == -1){
    perror("setting the handler");
    return 1;
  }

  new_timer.it_value.tv_sec = 2;
  new_timer.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
  new_timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
  new_timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;

  // Create the timer
  if(setitimer(ITIMER_REAL,&new_timer,NULL) == -1){
    perror("setting the timer");
    return 1;
  }

  for(int i = 1; ;i++){
    switch(pidarr[i] = fork()){
    case -1: // ERROR
      perror("setting the timer");
      return 1;
    case 0:
      for(;;) // Waiting to die
        ;
    case 1:
      wait(NULL);
      break;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I used `settimer()` (https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setitimer.3p.html) for create a two second timer and `sigaction()` (https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) for cast the signal, when the signal is arrived i will kill all the processes into the pidarr array, so **my** machine will not crush, if the timer was bigger we would have encountered the same problem, because the machine would crash before reaching the timer

Comment: thanks, I have deduced some ideas from your answer!